Is there a function for which $f(x) = x$ doesn’t give the same answer as $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$?
Is there a function for which $f(x) = x$ doesn’t give the same answer as $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$? (Here, $f^{-1}(x)$ is the usual inverse function of $f(x)$.)
I know it’s gotta be a decreasing function, but I can’t figure it out.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please, use MathJax to type the math in your questions. Unusual characters like ¹ won't render properly in many devices.

@SassatelliGiulio That doesn't work. The equation $f(x)=x$ have the set of solutions ${-6}$ which is also the set of solutions of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

@jjagmath Oh, now I see why. Sorry.

I'm assuming you are looking for functions $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which are invertible.
If $f(x)=x$ then $f(f(x))=f(x)=x$. Applying $f^{-1}$ you get $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, so any solution of $f(x)=x$ is also a solution of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$.
The other implication is false. Just take the function $f(x)=-x$. Then the equation $f(x)=x$ has only the solution $x=0$, but the equation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ is satisfied by all real numbers.
